# Clojure range-case macro

Tags: macros, clojure, case

In the book ["The Scheme Programming Language, 4th Edition"](http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/), by R. Kent Dybvig, on page 86, the author has written a `define-syntax` (Scheme macro) for a `case` statement that accepts ranges for its conditions. I thought I would try this in Clojure.

Here is the result.

How can I improve this? I use `:ii`, `:ie`, `:ei`, and `:ee` for the range operators, indicating inclusive-inclusive, inclusive-exclusive, exclusive-inclusive,
and exclusive-exclusive, respectively. Is there a better choice?

I chose to expand to a `cond` rather than discrete `if` statements because I felt that I would gain the benefit from any future improvements to the `cond` macro.

```
(defmacro range-case [target & cases]
  "Compare the target against a set of ranges or constant values and return
   the first one that matches. If none match, and there exists a case with the
   value :else, return that target. Each range consists of a vector containing
   3 terms: a lower bound, an operator, and an upper bound. The operator must
   be one of :ii, :ie, :ei, or :ee, which indicate that the range comparison
   should be inclusive-inclusive, inclusive-exclusive, exclusive-inclusive,
   or exclusive-exclusive, respectively.
   Example:
     (range-case target
                 [0.0 :ie 1.0] :greatly-disagree
                 [1.0 :ie 2.0] :disagree
                 [2.0 :ie 3.0] :neutral
                 [3.0 :ie 4.0] :agree
                 [4.0 :ii 5.0] :strongly-agree
                 42 :the-answer
                 :else :do-not-care)
   expands to
     (cond
       (and (<= 0.0 target) (< target 1.0)) :greatly-disagree
       (and (<= 1.0 target) (< target 2.0)) :disagree
       (and (<= 2.0 target) (< target 3.0)) :neutral
       (and (<= 3.0 target) (< target 4.0)) :agree
       (<= 4.0 target 5.0) :strongly-agree
       (= target 42) :the-answer
       :else :do-not-care)
    Test cases:
      (use '[clojure.test :only (deftest is run-tests)])
      (deftest unit-tests
        (letfn [(test-range-case [target]
                                 (range-case target
                                             [0.0 :ie 1.0] :greatly-disagree
                                             [1.0 :ie 2.0] :disagree
                                             [2.0 :ie 3.0] :neutral
                                             [3.0 :ie 4.0] :agree
                                             [4.0 :ii 5.0] :strongly-agree
                                             42 :the-answer
                                             :else :do-not-care))]
      (is (= (test-range-case 0.0) :greatly-disagree))
      (is (test-range-case 0.5) :greatly-disagree)
      (is (test-range-case 1.0) :disagree)
      (is (test-range-case 1.5) :disagree)
      (is (test-range-case 2.0) :neutral)
      (is (test-range-case 2.5) :neutral)
      (is (test-range-case 3.0) :agree)
      (is (test-range-case 3.5) :agree)
      (is (test-range-case 4.0) :strongly-agree)
      (is (test-range-case 4.5) :strongly-agree)
      (is (test-range-case 5.0) :strongly-agree)
      (is (test-range-case 42) :the-answer)
      (is (test-range-case -1) :do-not-care)))
    (run-tests)"
  `(cond
    ~@(loop [cases cases ret []]
        (cond
         (empty? cases)
         ret

         (odd? (count cases))
         (throw (IllegalArgumentException.
                 (str "no matching clause: " (first cases))))

         (= :else (first cases))
         (recur (drop 2 cases) (conj ret :else (second cases)))

         (vector? (first cases))
         (let [[lower-bound operator upper-bound] (first cases)
               clause (second cases)

               [condition clause]
               (case operator
                     :ii `((<= ~lower-bound ~target ~upper-bound) ~clause)
                     :ie `((and (<= ~lower-bound ~target)
                                (< ~target ~upper-bound)) ~clause)
                     :ei `((and (< ~lower-bound ~target)
                                (<= ~target ~upper-bound)) ~clause)
                     :ee `((< ~lower-bound ~target ~upper-bound) ~clause)
                     (throw (IllegalArgumentException.
                             (str "unknown operator: " operator))))]
           (recur (drop 2 cases) (conj ret condition clause)))

         :else
         (let [[condition clause]
               `[(= ~target ~(first cases)) ~(second cases)]]
           (recur (drop 2 cases) (conj ret condition clause)))))))
```

**UPDATE**: Here is the revised version incorporating changes suggested by [mikera](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214010/mikera) and [kotarak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/198935/kotarak):

```
(defmacro range-case [target & cases]
  "Compare the target against a set of ranges or constant values and return
   the first one that matches. If none match, and there exists a case with the
   value :else, return that target. Each range consists of a vector containing
   one of the following patterns:
     [upper-bound]                 if this is the first pattern, match any
                                   target <= upper-bound
                                   otherwise, match any target <= previous
                                   upper-bound and <= upper-bound
     [< upper-bound]               if this is the first pattern, match any
                                   target < upper-bound
                                   otherwise, match any target <= previous
                                   upper-bound and < upper-bound
     [lower-bound upper-bound]     match any target where lower-bound <= target
                                   and target <= upper-bound
     [< lower-bound upper-bound]   match any target where lower-bound < target
                                   and target <= upper-bound
     [lower-bound < upper-bound]   match any target where lower-bound <= target
                                   and target < upper-bound
     [< lower-bound < upper-bound] match any target where lower-bound < target
                                   and target < upper-bound
   Example:
     (range-case target
                 [0 < 1] :strongly-disagree
                 [< 2]     :disagree
                 [< 3]     :neutral
                 [< 4]     :agree
                 [5]       :strongly-agree
                 42          :the-answer
                 :else       :do-not-care)
   expands to
     (cond
       (and (<= 0 target) (< target 1)) :strongly-disagree
       (and (<= 1 target) (< target 2)) :disagree
       (and (<= 2 target) (< target 3)) :neutral
       (and (<= 3 target) (< target 4)) :agree
       (<= 4 target 5) :strongly-agree
       (= target 42) :the-answer
       :else :do-not-care)
    Test cases:
      (use '[clojure.test :only (deftest is run-tests)])
      (deftest unit-tests
        (letfn [(test-range-case [target]
                                 (range-case target
                                             [0 < 1] :strongly-disagree
                                             [< 2]   :disagree
                                             [< 3]   :neutral
                                             [< 4]   :agree
                                             [5]     :strongly-agree
                                             42      :the-answer
                                             :else   :do-not-care))]
      (is (= (test-range-case 0) :strongly-disagree))
      (is (= (test-range-case 0.5) :strongly-disagree))
      (is (= (test-range-case 1) :disagree))
      (is (= (test-range-case 1.5) :disagree))
      (is (= (test-range-case 2) :neutral))
      (is (= (test-range-case 2.5) :neutral))
      (is (= (test-range-case 3) :agree))
      (is (= (test-range-case 3.5) :agree))
      (is (= (test-range-case 4) :strongly-agree))
      (is (= (test-range-case 4.5) :strongly-agree))
      (is (= (test-range-case 5) :strongly-agree))
      (is (= (test-range-case 42) :the-answer))
      (is (= (test-range-case -1) :do-not-care))))
    (run-tests)"
  (if (odd? (count cases))
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. (str "no matching clause: "
                                           (first cases))))
    `(cond
      ~@(loop [cases cases ret [] previous-upper-bound nil]
          (cond
           (empty? cases)
           ret

           (= :else (first cases))
           (recur (drop 2 cases) (conj ret :else (second cases)) nil)

           (vector? (first cases))
           (let [condition (first cases)
                 clause (second cases)

                 [case-expr prev-upper-bound]
                 (let [length (count condition)]
                   (cond
                    (= length 1)
                    (let [upper-bound (first condition)]
                      [(if previous-upper-bound
                         `(and (<= ~previous-upper-bound ~target)
                               (<= ~target ~upper-bound))
                         `(<= ~target ~upper-bound))
                       upper-bound])

                    (= length 2)
                    (if (= '< (first condition))
                      (let [[_ upper-bound] condition]
                        [(if previous-upper-bound
                           `(and (<= ~previous-upper-bound ~target)
                                 (< ~target ~upper-bound))
                           `(< ~target ~upper-bound))
                         upper-bound])
                      (let [[lower-bound upper-bound] condition]
                        [`(and (<= ~lower-bound ~target)
                               (<= ~target ~upper-bound))
                         upper-bound]))

                    (= length 3)
                    (cond
                     (= '< (first condition))
                     (let [[_ lower-bound upper-bound] condition]
                       [`(and (< ~lower-bound ~target)
                              (<= ~target ~upper-bound))
                        upper-bound])

                     (= '< (second condition))
                     (let [[lower-bound _ upper-bound] condition]
                       [`(and (<= ~lower-bound ~target)
                              (< ~target ~upper-bound))
                        upper-bound])

                     :else
                     (throw (IllegalArgumentException. (str "unknown pattern: "
                                                            condition))))

                    (and (= length 4)
                         (= '< (first condition))
                         (= '< (nth condition 3)))
                    (let [[_ lower-bound _ upper-bound] condition]
                      [`(and (< ~lower-bound ~target) (< ~target ~upper-bound))
                       upper-bound])

                    :else
                    (throw (IllegalArgumentException. (str "unknown pattern: "
                                                           condition)))))]
             (recur (drop 2 cases)
                    (conj ret case-expr clause)
                    prev-upper-bound))

           :else
           (let [[condition clause]
                 `[(= ~target ~(first cases)) ~(second cases)]]
             (recur (drop 2 cases) (conj ret condition clause) nil)))))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would also vote for something slightly more verbose but less ugly to read.

```
 (range-case target
   [(<= 0.0) (< 1.0)] :greatly-disagree
   [(<= 1.0) (< 2.0)] :disagree
   [(<= 2.0) (< 3.0)] :neutral
   [(<= 3.0) (< 4.0)] :agree
   (<= 4.0 5.0)       :strongly-agree
   42 :the-answer
   :else :do-not-care)
```

This could be a viable alternative.

Comment: Your suggestion, combined with mikera's suggestions for "default" operators and an implicit lower bound could be useful. Will investigate.

Comment: Maybe even `[LB UB]`, `[LB < UB]`, `[< LB UB]`, and `[< LB < UB]` for `:ii`, `:ie`, `:ei`, and `:ee`, respectively, with the default operator being `<=`.

Answer (score 3):

Some ideas:

- Have a default value for the operator (e.g. ":ie" would probably be most natural in typical problems)
- Have one of the bounds default to the previous or following upper/lower bound so that you don't need to repeat the same bounding values.
- Consider ifs rather than cond so that you can do interval bisection (would be a performance win if you expect very large numbers of cases)

An alternative might be to make your macro work at the case level like follows:

```
(cond
  (in-range target [0.0 1.0]) :greatly-disagree)
  (in-range target [1.0 2.0]) :disagree)
  ...)
```

I personally like this because you can mix your range tests with other predicates if needed.

Comment: @mikera: That's as verbose as the regular `cond` :-). I like your first two comments, though. I'll explore them further.

Comment: As a general principle I don't think minimising verbosity is a particularly useful objective... I'd choose readability, maintainability and consistency any day over and above saving a few characters of typing :-)

Comment: @mikera: I agree. I was being a smart-ass. Your suggestion for `(in-range ...)` should be another macro, though. It would be very useful by itself.

Comment: @mikera: With regard to your suggestion for an implicit lower bound, in the first case clause, if the lower bound is omitted, it could (implicitly) be `(- Integer/MAX_INTEGER)` (without actually adding a `(< (- Integer/MAX_INTEGER) target)` to the growing `cond`). I'm not sure I understand the "interval bisection" you mentioned.

Comment: @Ralph the interval bisection just means that you take the middle case first - if the target is e.g. < 2.0 then you never need to check any of the higher cases at all since they must necessarily be false. Hence you eliminate half of the cases with just one test. It basically turns the complexity from O(n) to O(log n) if you have n cases, so can be worth doing if n is large.

Comment: @mikera: Ahh! Very interesting optimization. Gotta think about implementation. This could still be implemented using `cond`, though, since `cond` evaluates from top to bottom. It would require rearranging the cases -- ok if they don't overlap. I keep telling myself "It's not code. It's just data." :-)

Comment: @Ralph - cond can work for interval bisection however you will need to nest multiple conds - the reason is that you basically need to do a different set of subsequent tests depending on the outcome of the first test (i.e. two completely separate branches).

Answer (score 3):

My initial take on it:

```
(defn make-case [test val]
  (if (vector? test)
    `((and ~@(for [[lower comp upper] (partition 3 2 test)]
               (list comp lower upper)))
      ~val)

    (list :else val)))

(defmacro range-case [& cases]
  (let [cases (partition 2 cases)]
    `(cond ~@(mapcat (partial apply make-case) cases))))
```

This requires a slight change to syntax, like this:

```
(range-case 
 [0.0 <= x < 1.0] :greatly-disagree
 [1.0 <= x < 2.0] :disagree
 [2.0 <= x < 3.0] :neutral
 [3.0 <= x < 4.0] :agree
 [4.0 <= x <= 5.0] :strongly-agree
 [42 = x] :the-answer
 :else :do-not-care)
```

My version may be violating the spirit of the original example, but "advantages" include:

1. You aren't hard-coded to a single `target`.  You also aren't limited to two tests (lower test and upper test).  You could do `[0 < x <= y < 4 <= z]` etc.
2. Syntax more closely resembles mathematical comparison notation.
3. Clojure's comparison operators can be passed as parameters themselves; no need to use keywords and translate those into comparison operators.  This way, the comparison operators aren't hard-coded into the function, and removing this layer of indirection makes it read a bit better.
4. Equality is no longer a special case.

Disadvantages?

1. `x` is repeated a bunch of times.  Is grabbing `x` and putting it at the top worth the increase in complexity and decrease in flexibility?
2. Like your original example, this uses infix notation.  It may be a bit jarring, in a world of prefix notation.

Then again, at this point our macro isn't doing much more than changing square brackets into parens and `and`ing a bunch of stuff together.  So I question whether you really need a macro at all.

```
(defn ?? [& xs]
  (every? (fn [[lower comp upper]]
            (comp lower upper))
          (partition 3 2 xs)))

(cond
  (?? 0.0 <= x < 1.0) :greatly-disagree
  (?? 1.0 <= x < 2.0) :disagree
  (?? 2.0 <= x < 3.0) :neutral
  (?? 3.0 <= x < 4.0) :agree
  (?? 4.0 <= x <= 5.0) :strongly-agree
  (= 42 x) :the-answer
  :else :do-not-care)
```

Comment: Thanks. "So I question whether you really need a macro at all." It is more an exercise in macro-writing than anything really useful.