# Clojure simple pattern matching

Tags: macros, clojure, pattern-matching

As a follow up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344454/clojure-range-case-macro), I am trying to implement a simple pattern matching in Clojure.

I would like something like the following:

```
(match target
  [ub]    expr1    ; ub should be bound to actual value in expr1
  ['< ub] expr2    ; match the literal less-than symbol
                   ; and ub should be bound to actual value in expr2
  [lb ub] expr3    ; lb and ub should be bound to actual values in expr3
  :else   expr4    ; default case if none match
)
```

Usage:

```
(match [< 5.0] ...)
```

should arrange to execute `expr2` at runtime.

I would like to write a macro, but I am not sure of the expansion.

I am considering having each case-and-clause expand to a `let` with bindings to internal variables and checks that the literal symbols (`'<`) actually matches the pattern. Maybe for the second pattern (`['< ub]`):

```
(let [[sym1 ub] pattern]
  (if (= '< sym1)
    expr1)
```

Do I need to use `(gensym)` for the bindings? How?

Bigger picture:

```
(range-case target
            [0.0 < 1.0] :greatly-disagree
            [< 2.0]     :disagree
            [< 3.0]     :neutral
            [< 4.0]     :agree
            [5.0]       :strongly-agree
            42          :the-answer
            :else       :do-not-care)
```

I am trying to match the `[...]` patterns and convert them to the following:

```
[ub]          (if previous-ub `(and (<= ~previous-ub ~target) (<= ~target ~ub))
                              `(< ~target ~ub))
['< ub]       (if previous-ub `(and (<= ~previous-ub ~target) (< ~target ~ub))
                              `(< ~target ~ub))
[lb ub]       `(and (<= ~lb ~target) (<= ~target ~ub))
['< lb ub]    `(and (< ~lb ~target) (<= ~target ~ub))
[lb '< ub]    `(and (<= ~lb ~target) (< ~target ~ub))
['< lb '< ub] `(and (< ~lb ~target) (< ~target ~ub))
```

I have a `cond` that checks that the case part is a vector. This pattern match should occur inside that case.

Comment: have you looked around at the existing pattern matching tools for Clojure? matchure for example looks pretty interesting: http://spin.atomicobject.com/2010/04/25/matchure-serious-clojure-pattern-matching/

Comment: @mikera: Yeah. I'm just trying to figure macros out and hope that writing them will shed some light.

Comment: ah that's cool then. reinventing wheels is perfectly fine as long as you are trying to learn the art of wheelmaking!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first idea was basically the same: Bind stuff to internal locals and test on their contents in a big `and`. For literals the value is bound to a generated local; symbols are used directly in the binding.

I also added a check that the spec vector matches the length of the target vector. Otherwise you can't have `[ub]` as well as `[lb ub]` since neither contains a check which could fail. So always the first would be selected.

Here is the code:

```
(defn make-clause
  [expr-g [spec expr & more :as clause]]
  (when (seq clause)
    (let [tests-and-bindings (map (fn [x]
                                    (if-not (symbol? x)
                                      (let [x-g (gensym "x")]
                                        [`(= ~x ~x-g) x-g])
                                      [nil x]))
                                  spec)
          tests    (keep first tests-and-bindings)
          bindings (map second tests-and-bindings)]
      `(let [[~@bindings] ~expr-g]
         (if (and (= (count ~expr-g) ~(count spec)) ~@tests)
           ~expr
           ~(make-clause expr-g more))))))

(defmacro match
  [expr & clauses]
  (let [expr-g  (gensym "expr")]
    `(let ~[expr-g expr]
       ~(make-clause expr-g clauses))))
```

And an example expansion. I didn't use syntax-quote in the example to reduce the noise in the expansion, but you should get the idea.

```
(let [expr98 [(quote <) 3.0]]
  (let [[ub] expr98]
    (if (and (= (count expr98) 1))
      (if previous-ub
        (and (<= previous-ub target) (<= target ub))
        (< target ub))
      (let [[x99 ub] expr98]
        (if (and (= (count expr98) 2) (= (quote <) x99))
          (if previous-ub
            (and (<= previous-ub target) (< target ub))
            (< target ub))
          (let [[lb ub] expr98]
            (if (and (= (count expr98) 2))
              (and (<= lb target) (<= target ub))
              nil)))))))
```

The invokation was:

```
(match ['< 3.0]
  [ub]    (if previous-ub
            (and (<= previous-ub target) (<= target ub))
            (< target ub))
  ['< ub] (if previous-ub
            (and (<= previous-ub target) (< target ub))
            (< target ub))
  [lb ub] (and (<= lb target) (<= target ub))))
```

Hope that helps you get started.

Comment: @kotarak: I thought about the problem at 1AM while staring at the ceiling :-). I'm going to try out my ideas before exploring yours to see if I can get it to work. After all, this whole thing is an exercise in learning macros (mostly). My idea is to traverse the list of patterns/expressions and form `cond` clauses with a test for the literals and a `let` block for the bindings. BTW, "Let Over Lambda", by Doug Hoyte, while written for Common Lisp, is giving me some great ideas for macros in Clojure.

Comment: @ralph you should definitively explore your ideas! I decided against a `cond`, BTW. Maybe you have similar considerations but decide for it. Let's see. All-in-all I'm pretty happy that there are macros available, but found that I don't use them thaaat often in Clojure.

Comment: @ralph and in the end have a look at matchjure to see how the experts do it. ;)

Comment: @kotarak: Looking at your expansion, I see that each new pattern is nested inside the previous one. That means that each pattern can "see" the bindings from the previous one. Shadowing will hide the overridden symbols, but the other bindings are still visible. That may or may not be a problem, depending on how you want it to behave. I was considering ways of nesting the `let` blocks so that each pattern hides its bindings from subsequent ones. Maybe that is the reason your chose `if` statements instead of `cond`.

Comment: @kotarak: "I also added a check that the spec vector matches the length of the target vector." I was also thinking about this last night. Another extension might be to support `[item item ... :when condition]` and allow patterns similar to those in Scala. The item count would have to match the target count. You could also allow `:val symbol` that gets replaced with the symbol's current binding. My idea is growing into a full implementation of matchure :-).

Comment: @ralph Ah. That's indeed an issue I didn't anticipate. The shadowing might be troublesome of there is a binding in the environment you don't want to have shadowed in a later clause. `(let [x ..] (match .. ['< x] "x shadowed here" ['> y] "x should not be shadowed here")`

Comment: @kotarak: You might be able to move the `let` block to the "then" or "else" part of each `if` statement. "Mentally" expand a `cond` and see how that is structured. `cond` "isolates" its clauses. BTW, matchure has a nice way of binding variables: `?foo`.

Comment: @ralph I don't particularly like `?foo`. Magic names are not my favourite. I'd prefer plain symbols - however named. My issue with `cond` was that the test and the clause are separated and you basically need two steps to extract the required information. I tried to be clever and save one of these steps. Well, maybe too clever.